# Google Apps Script: testing doPost() with cURL

Tags: http, curl, google-apps-script

I have created a very basic Google Apps Script. Here is my `doPost()` and `doGet()`:

```
function doPost(e) {
  return respond(JSON.stringify({result: "Hello world!"}));
}

function doGet(e) {
  return respond(JSON.stringify({result: "Hello world!"})); 
}

function respond(response) {  
  return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(response)
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}
```

I have deployed the app with a new version. It is set to run as me but everyone can run it including anonymous.

I am testing the endpoint by running cURL from the command line, and for GET it works as expected:

Request -

```
curl -L https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxYxgMfMkR6hGI5UO2Gn8tg369oqsy_W41-olb0Do1y8gOjaNvm/exec
```

Response -

```
{"result":"Hello world!"}
```

But for POST:

Request -

```
curl -H "Content-Length: 0" -D "p=p" -X POST -L https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxYxgMfMkR6hGI5UO2Gn8tg369oqsy_W41-olb0Do1y8gOjaNvm/exec
```

Response -

```
Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.

Please check the address and try again.
```

As you can see from the command, I had to manipulate things a bit to get this far: including dummy data, adding a content-length header, and adding the -L flag to consume the redirect.

However, I am stuck. Why can't it "find the file"? Why does it think there is a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you'll need to send data.

This works (I got `{"result":"POST request received!"}`):

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d {} -L https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxYxgMfMkR6hGI5UO2Gn8tg369oqsy_W41-olb0Do1y8gOjaNvm/exec
```

As does this:

```
curl -d "" -L https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxYxgMfMkR6hGI5UO2Gn8tg369oqsy_W41-olb0Do1y8gOjaNvm/exec
```

Comment: Thank you, but you left out "-X POST" so you're really sending a GET request.

Comment: The default Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded and it specifies the format of the data being *sent* not the data being *received*, see: https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58

Comment: Good point ha ha, sorry - edited; I changed it to a POST by adding -d {} (I also got the same result as you with the explicit "-X POST", not usually how I do POSTS so I'm probably missing something on the command line there)

Comment: That's so weird! Getting rid of "-X POST" does make it work. I am flummoxed by that but very grateful. Thank you!

Comment: I'm still not sure whether this is just me not completely understanding precisely how curl/POST works, but here's an open Google Issue Tracker issue that might be relevant or related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62196692

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! +1000 After banging my head on this for an hour, this answer finally saved me. Here's why it works (as can be seen with `curl -v`): In both cases the initial request is a POST. But with the `-X POST` the subsequent request (the redirect to fetch the response which should be a GET) is forced as a POST as well and fails. You will note that the script actually does run, but it's the response that fails with this error. This is just some oddball detail of curl.

Comment: And to clarify: The solution is basically to eliminate the `-X POST` which is what causes the problem on the redirect.

Comment: @dkamins Thank you for following up, it's great to finally know why this happens!

Comment: Essentially when you use -d/--raw-data you give curl enough information to infer that you're making a POST request. If you explicitly tell curl -X/--request POST then you're saying use the POST method regardless of a redirect (where you should be using a GET).

So by removing the explicit "-X POST" does actually send a POST request, and then a GET when you hit a 302 when using "-d/--data-raw" :)

Here's some useful reading material: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60845042/curl-redirect-302-not-changing-the-method-from-post-to-get

https://ec.haxx.se/http/http-redirects