# Testing Google Script with PostMan

Tags: google-apps-script, postman

I have created a Google Script and published it as a web app, [very much like this post has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618265/google-apps-script-testing-dopost-with-curl).

However, I would like to call my extremely simple `doGet` method using Postman. The web app is published with anonymous access and execution permission as me.

I was expecting to be able to paste the URL into Postman, set the `GET` verb and hit `Send` - and to see the same result I see in the browser. I do not.

What am I doing wrong?

**[UPDATE] Responding to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540572/testing-google-script-with-postman#comment103405541_58540572) by [themaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster)**

I have created a `Google Apps Script` called `devices` in my Google Drive. I've added this function:

```
function doDelete(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('{"test":"yes"}');
}
```

Simple, I know, but should respond to a `DELETE` request with:

```
{
  "test": "yes"
}
```

I then hit `Save`, followed by `Deploy` > `Publish as web app...` with the following options:

- Project version: new
- Execute the app as: me
- Who has access: Anyone, even anonymous

I hit `Update` and get a URL like this:

https://script.google.com/macros/s/ABcdefgHInmLDGiHmpGmXkXIxMjsh0s61sKZ9ov6OOSpkb--1quTtfM/exec

If the function is named `doGet` and I paste the URL into the browser, I see this JSON mentioned above.

If I leave the function named `doDelete` and I make a `DELETE` request from Postman, I get this:

> Could not get any response There was an error connecting to
>   https://script.google.com/macros/s/ABcdefgHInmLDGiHmpGmXkXIxMjsh0s61sKZ9ov6OOSpkb--1quTtfM/exec.
>   Why this might have happened: The server couldn't send a response:
>   Ensure that the backend is working properly Self-signed SSL
>   certificates are being blocked: Fix this by turning off 'SSL
>   certificate verification' in Settings > General Proxy configured
>   incorrectly Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings >
>   Proxy Request timeout: Change request timeout in Settings > General

If I change the function to `doGet`, republish and call it with a `GET` request from Postman, I get the same result.

**[EDIT] Clarification**

If I make the Postman call using `GET` and have the `doGet` function setup to call an IFTTT webhook, the webhook does fire. I can also make it fire using the `doPost` and a `POST` request in Postman.

However, if I use `doDelete` with a `DELETE` request in Postman, the IFTTT webhook does not get called.

Regardless of the verb used in Postman I do not get a response - only the message quoted above.

**[EDIT] Response to [@sourabh-choraria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10713297/sourabh-choraria) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540572/testing-google-script-with-postman/58561099?noredirect=1#comment103468522_58561099)**

My code currently is just this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('{"valid":"no"}');
}
```

Published with the process described above, I get this when calling with Postman:

```
Could not get any response
```

I am making that request as a `GET` without any headers.

Comment: What do you see instead? See [mre]

Comment: I'm assuming the issue is that I haven't got an authentication token in the header being sent by Postman, but I'm not sure how to acquire that when my browser doesn't seem to need it. Then again, I assume that's because I'm signed into my browser with the same account that the request is being run from/for. But then... the web app is set to allow anonymous access, so auth requirements would be moot, no?

Comment: I have a suspicion that google apps scripts do not support HTTP verbs other than GET and POST with simple function names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Google Apps Script's Web Apps only support the following HTTP methods, as per [their requirements for web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#requirements_for_web_apps) -

- **GET** via `doGet()`
- **POST** via `doPost()`

While not explicitly stated in the reference doc that PUT, DELETE, UPDATE etc. are unsupported, there is no way to execute those HTTP methods via Web Apps in Apps Script.

Comment: Thanks for the info - it jibes with what I was expecting to get confirmed. Do you know why the requests (even for POST and GET) are not returning any content in Postman, even when I am returning HTML content?

Comment: That’s odd. I too use Postman and it always does. Do you mind sharing the code for either of them?